# bookmarklet - Fill loop (input boxes) makes page with unwanted changes

Tags: javascript, loops, input, fill

So this is my code, it's very simple example of loop which will fill input boxes with corresponding array values

```
var aList=document.getElementsByTagName('input');
for(var i = 0, len = aList.length; i < len; ++i){ 
document.getElementById(aList[i].id).value=I[i][1][0][0];}
```

[image]

When I run this code from bookmarklet, it will just change website body to

```
<body>OCENIE</body>
```

What is wrong with code? It does not go out of array size, if I will run this from firebug console (or other dev tool) it works like on screen, all values are filled, but with bookmarklet it creates new page...

Answer (score 0):

Ok I've made this, it seems (I am noT js programmer!) that this code is equal to something like:

```
javascript: I[lastValueOf_i][1][0][0];
```

In practice it would be

```
javascript: "OCENIE"
```

which will open new page with content:

```
<body>OCENIE</body>
```

All what I had to do was to put code into void (non-returning) function

```
fillInputs();

function fillInputs()
{
    var NList = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
    for (var i=0; i<NList.length; i++) { NList[i].value = I[i][1][0][0]; }
}
```

Case solved :)